# Microsoft Graph API creates empty deleted messages after removing contact

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I have a powershell script to synchronise contacts with contacts database in my company. The script works everyday in the night and there is a problem when contact is deleted. After removing a contact through Microsoft Graph Api there are two new draft e-mails in deleted items folder. First one looks like an e-mail but it has empty subject, sender etc, the second one is a deleted contact which I could restore. I'm not happy with my deleted items folder full of empty mails so I wonder how to prevent this. When I search for deleted messages those messages aren't shown so I can't delete them through api. Any idea?

Update:

- I've tried beta version it didn't help.
- I found out that there is the same problem when I delete contact in my mobile and outlook is not running  - I can see draft empty mails in deleted emails folder.
- When I search for deleted messages I can see its proper amount (i.e. I've got 150 empty draft mails) and I can see that there are 150 messages but when I try to see those messages there is none.

Comment: Have you tried with beta version. Are you facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I still don't know what is wrong. I've updated the description to sum up my findings.